# I got 'Invalid according to Policy' error respo se when I try to use node.js AWS S3 'createPresignedPost' with 'metadata'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use AWS S3 presigned URL using Node.js AWS SDK.
And I want to add custom metadata on S3 object about user data.

So I added "x-amz-meta-userid" at "Fields" and "Conditions" for 'createPresignedPost'.

```js
  const result: S3.PresignedPost = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.createPresignedPost({
      Bucket: "my-bucket",
      Fields: {
        key: "my-image",
        "x-amz-meta-userid": "1",
      },
      Expires: 60 * 5, // 5 minutes (unit: seconds)
      Conditions: [
        ["content-length-range", 0, 50 * 1024 * 1024 * 10], // 0 ~ 10mb
        ["eq", "$x-amz-meta-userid", "1"],
      ],

    }, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }

      data.fields["x-amz-meta-userid"] = "1";
      return resolve(data);
    });
  });
```

But when I use the presigned URL that I created, it responsed like this.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$x-amz-meta-userid", "1"]</Message>
    <RequestId>753WHC9TX37JY7C1</RequestId>
    <HostId>DYC2smyh+g4JDGbdlFx1Ub/1YPmexgvCrresMw0KeEE1V3tEMZnbC5F6JtAGUWP+Oegu7kaplHA=</HostId>
</Error>
```

This is request code created by Postman. (I used Postman)

```js
var axios = require('axios');
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');

var data = new FormData();
data.append('key', 'my-image');
data.append('bucket', 'my-bucket');
data.append('X-Amz-Algorithm', 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256');
data.append('X-Amz-Credential', 'xxxx');
data.append('X-Amz-Date', '20220529T130050Z');
data.append('Policy', 'xxxx');
data.append('X-Amz-Signature', 'xxxx');
data.append('file', fs.createReadStream('my-photo.jpf'));
data.append('x-amz-meta-userid', '1');

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket',
  headers: { 
    ...data.getHeaders()
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

I'm not sure that I made a mistake or I can't add metadata for S3 presigned URL.
(When I tried to use 'createPresignedPost' without "x-amz-meta-userid", it worked well)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and as awkward as it may sound I solved it by changing the order of the params and sending the file parameter at the end, try like this:

```
.... 
var data = new FormData();
data.append('key', 'my-image');
data.append('bucket', 'my-bucket');
data.append('X-Amz-Algorithm', 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256');
data.append('X-Amz-Credential', 'xxxx');
data.append('X-Amz-Date', '20220529T130050Z');
data.append('Policy', 'xxxx');
data.append('X-Amz-Signature', 'xxxx');
data.append('x-amz-meta-userid', '1');
data.append('file', fs.createReadStream('my-photo.jpf'));
...
```